# How to Get Google Tag ID from the tag google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using google_tag_manager tag in my page to fetch the details and returning the JSON of the data layer, the problem is i am not able to get the tag manager id, i need to get it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTbQd.png)

this image we can find how to fetch the GTM ID dynamicaly